# Mongodb aggregation pipeline optimization - 2 stage of $match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I am researching on performance optimization of aggregation pipeline recently. I came across this problem when deciding which to index. I set a compound index for  `{'receiverId': 1,'type': 1 }` . 
My original pipeline looks like this. I am thinking whether indexing the `isRead` 
is necessary too. The reason why I didn't create a three fields compound index because other queries only use `recieverId` and `type` only.

```
notifications.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            'recieverId': ObjectId(xxx),
            'type': xxx,
            'isRead': false
        }
    },
    {
     ...
    },
], (err, result) => {
    return res.status(200).json(result);
});
```

So, I changed to this below. wondering if pipeline like this could save some calculation cost after filtering the `recieverId` and `type`. Will the `isRead`, second `$match` filter from the result of the first `$match`?

```
notifications.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            'recieverId': ObjectId(xxx),
            'type': xxx,
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'isRead': false
        }
    },
    {
     ...
    },
], (err, result) => {
    return res.status(200).json(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually dosen't matter how you write this as mongo will optimize this pipeline.

From the docs:

> When a $match immediately follows another $match, the two stages can coalesce into a single $match.

Read about it and other pipeline optimizations mongo does [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#match-match-coalescence).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I read about that, I also did a pipeline testing in studio 3T and still thinking whether to create a compound index including the `isRead` field because the value will change whenever the user read it. Any suggestion on the query above?

Comment: Adding the `isRead` field to your index would help mongo by not needing to filter on it. meaning it will help run-time. one thing to consider (which is not a problem for most people) is the index size which in this case shouldn't be much different.

Comment: Noted with thanks, one last question, for example, I have total 5 query, first 4 only query the `recieverId` & `type` fields, only the last one query three fields `recieverId` , `type` & `isRead', does one compound index ( 3 fields) is enough to support all 5 query?

Comment: Yes (dependant on index build order), for example index `{x, y, z}` can support queries on `x` , `x,y` and `x,y,z`. also read about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes).